# Can i hook run a 110 plug off my dryer out let and still have my dryer outlet and a plug out side for things

Tags: electrical

Can i run a 110 outdoor plug off my dryer plug in my laundry room.i have new wire to run and new plug

Comment: Loren:  This site expects the person asking the question to do some basic research before asking here.  A simple google query such as this:  "tapping dryer circuit for 120" would give you the answers you need.   Not meaning to be critical, but this question has been asked and answered many times on the net.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add a 120v branch for a washer to a 240v dryer circuit?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/129602/can-i-add-a-120v-branch-for-a-washer-to-a-240v-dryer-circuit)

Comment: Is your dryer electric or gas?

Comment: Can you post a photo of your dryer outlet, with the dryer unplugged, please?

Answer (score 4):

I know this has been asked before, but the simple answer is no, you cannot connect a normal 15 or 20A outlet to a 30A dryer circuit.

Comment: I found the duplicate after a bit of searching